# How do you have an attribute called "property" and use the @property decorator?

Tags: python, django, properties, built-in

I have a bit of a problem, and I've tried googling, but it doesn't turn up anything helpful.

I'm designing a django application and I want/need to have a field called "property". The reason for this is that *is* the technical title of the thing I'm trying to manage, and where possible I'd like to keep the business terminology.

Now this hasn't been a problem... up until now.

I now need to have a method, that I'd like to be able to use as a property, but there is a bit of a clash around the use of the token `property`.

```
class DataElementConcept(trebleObject):
    template = "polls/dataElementConcept.html"
    objectClass = models.ForeignKey(ObjectClass,blank=True,null=True)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property,blank=True,null=True)

    @property
    def registryCascadeItems(self):
        return [self.objectClass,self.property]
```

I understandably get this error.

```
  File "/home/theodore/Github/possum-mdr/polls/models.py", line 381, in DataElementConcept
    @property
TypeError: 'ForeignKey' object is not callable
```

**Is there a way around this that lets me treat this method as a property, and keep the `property` attribute?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
# On the module-level, do a workaround reference
# as property() is just a normal built-in function
_property = property 

class Foobar:
   property = ....


   @_property
   def registryCascadeItems(self):
       ....
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the "fully-qualified" name of the builtin property:

```
import __builtin__

@__builtin__.property
def registryCascadeItems(self): ...
```

Of course, I used quotations around the term "fully-qualified" because this is not a pythonic term. There are no name-qualifications in python. What this really is, is just another place where the original `property` is defined and can be accessed.

IMHO, this also makes your code more readable. There is no doubt what kind of property is involved -- you explicitly refer to the builtin one.

Comment: (You will need to import the [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) module to do this.)